# How to install an older version of Node.js with NVM on Mac M1 chipset

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh, apple-m1, nvm

I'm struggling with this problem for few days already, how to get version 10.24.1 of Node.js on my MacBook Pro with M1 chipset. It seems to install that version but once I open another terminal or close the existing terminal and open a new one there is the latest version of node (16.8.0)

These are the steps that I had followed:

- installed brew

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

`brew update`

- installed nvm

`brew install nvm`

- created a directory for it

`mkdir ~/.nvm`

- edited the file

`vim ~/.zshrc`

- with this snippet:

`export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm`

`source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

- load it

`source ~/.zshrc`

- installed the wanted version of node

`nvm install 10.24.1`

- check it, works fine, it shows this version when `node -v`
- use the version:

`nvm use 10.24.1`

Now, if I search `nvm -v` it returns `0.38.0`, if I search `node -v` it returns `10.24.1`. Everything as it should be. The problem is that this is not saved: if I open a new terminal and type the same commands, for `nvm -v` it shows the same value but the node version is the latest one, `16.8.0`.

Also tried the whole process with running `arch -x86_64 zsh` before starting but same result.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nvm alias default 10`

Change 10 to whatever [LTS or other version](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) of node you wish your default to be.

Comment: Make sure to `nvm install 10` to install the node version before setting the default